# Solr synonym multiple source files with different case sensitivity

Tags: solr, synonym

I have multiple synonym files for a solr (7) instance. Typically I would merge these files into one for each fieldType but some of the files require case sensitivity, and others require insensitivity. I have tried adding two filters i.e.

```
<filter class="solr.SynonymGraphFilterFactory" synonyms="mysynonymsA.txt" ignoreCase="false" expand="true"/>
<filter class="solr.SynonymGraphFilterFactory" synonyms="mysynonymsB.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
```

which seems to break when both are hit (note: at search time). An example of this would be the files

```
mysynonymsA.txt
ALPHA => ALPHA, BETA GAMMA

mysynonymsB.txt
DELTA, BETA GAMMA
```

When hitting ALPHA expanding to

```
ALPHA
ALPHA, BETA GAMMA
ALPHA, DELTA, BETA GAMMA
```

on the analysis screen, but having the result from explain on a search being

```
(ALPHA | GAMMA)
```

From my interpretation of the position value on the Analysis interface it looks like it is not building the graph correctly; unfortunately I don't currently have the numbers with me.

So my questions are:

1) Is this approach even possible?

2) If so what am I doing wrong?

3) If not is there a better solution other than duplication of case insensitive synonyms in different case patterns?

Comment: did you ever find a solution?   @oybon